# crop image with a margin top and bottom

Tags: c#, crop

i have a image

[image]

i must crop with a "margin" top and bottom. i write this code but works only top margin

```
public static Bitmap Crop(Image myImage)
{
    Bitmap croppedBitmap = new Bitmap(myImage);
    croppedBitmap = croppedBitmap.Clone(
                    new Rectangle(100,100,myImage.Width - 100,myImage.Height - 100),
                    System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.DontCare);
    return croppedBitmap;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to remove **twice** the margin from height and width:

```
public static Bitmap Crop(Image myImage)
{
    Bitmap croppedBitmap = new Bitmap(myImage);
    croppedBitmap = croppedBitmap.Clone(
                    new Rectangle(100,100,myImage.Width - 200,myImage.Height - 200),
                    System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.DontCare);
    return croppedBitmap;
}
```

further, by the image you post, it appear there is no left and right margin, but you did try to remove in code.

Comment: it was only a test. the left and right margins should be removed. but if you'd wanted to leave the 16: 9?